# Как сделать адаптивный фон?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка, background

На странице резкий переход от черного фона в белый, на черном фоне белый текс и при сжатии текст сжимается, а фон нет и получается так, что белый текст на белом фоне.

Comment: Вы бы привели пример того, каким именно образом у вас прописаны стили css для текста и фона, привели бы фрагмент html. Считаете, кто-то будет догадываться?

Comment: "Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно", как говорится)) Разметку страницы и скрин проблемы бы глянуть, а то в тексте вопроса даже вопроса как такового нет. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организуйте структуру так:

HTML:

```
<section class="white"> ... </section>
<section class="black"> ... </section>
```

CSS:

```
.white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
.black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Это очень упрощённо, но при такой структуре ничего не будет вылазить не туда.